# How do I create a function pointer typedef using SymbolicC

Tags: code-generation

I am just getting started with the [SymbolicC package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/SymbolicC/tutorial/Overview.html), and am trying to figure out how to handle function pointer typedefs, like, say:

```
typedef double (*rhs)(double, double);
```

The problem is that the [`CTypedef`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/SymbolicC/ref/CTypedef.html) function expects its arguments to be `CTypedef[type, var]`, which isn't really how function pointer declarationss in C work. An ordinary pointer typedef is done using `CDereference`, as:

```
CTypedef["double", CDereference["xp"]]
```

I'm not sure how to make that work in the context of `CFunction`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel slightly foolish for posting this, because I figured it our almost immediately after posting my question, but the answer is to follow C's philosophy that type declaration should mimic use. `CFunction` is used only for **function** declaration and definition; for function types, you use [`CCall`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/SymbolicC/ref/CCall.html):

```
CTypedef["double", CCall[CDereference[rhs], {"double", "double"}]]
```

`ToCCodeString` turns this into:

```
typedef double *rhs(double, double);
```

Comment: Well, whatever makes you reappear here again, is not foolish :). +1.

Comment: May I join the choir? :)